# Explicit Log Level instead of MinimumLevel for Serilog

Tags: c#, serilog

Is there any way I can configure exactly ONE log level per file in serilog?

I know I can configure one file per "MinimumLevel", but that is not what I need.

Comment: Are you trying to separate errors from information messages? You can write errors to a separate sink using `restrictedToMinimumLevel`. Removing errors from the common log isn't the best idea though. You won't be able to see what was going on before the error messages were logged and what led up to them

Comment: Don't think so, the doc seems pretty clear. https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis! Can you add an answer with an example?

Comment: Is *that* what you want to do? Put all events in a common file eg `log.txt` and create a separate error log for error events?

Comment: No I need each file to have ONLY the events of exactly one log level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar requirement. After some research, I added the following in the Startup class of my .net core 2.2 web api:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(evt => evt.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
        .WriteTo.RollingFile("C:\\Temp\\erros-logs.txt"))
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(evt => evt.Level == LogEventLevel.Information)
        .WriteTo.RollingFile("C:\\Temp\\info-logs.txt"))
    .CreateLogger();
```

If you are reading the settings from appsettings.json file and you want to use the above, you should transfer your logic from the file.

My answer is heavily inspired from the following post:
[Restrict to level](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile/issues/45)

Answer (score 4):

[*Serilog.Sinks.Map*](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map/) can be used for this without introducing too much duplication:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Map(le => le.Level, (level, wt) => wt.File($"C:\\Temp\\{level}-logs.txt"));
```