# How to log exception in separate file from the normal logs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, logging, serilog

I had this code in my program.cs

```
// Logging service Serilogs
builder.Logging.AddSerilog();
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(
    path: "logs/log-.txt",
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}{NewLine}",
    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information
    )
    .WriteTo.File(
                path: "logs/exceptions-.txt",
                outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}{NewLine}",
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error // Log only errors and above
            ).CreateLogger();
```

I am getting two logs while error is occured. One is normal logs with excception logs in it and another one is with only exception.

Is there any flag or anything that can determine in which file I want to write the logs in?

I tried created a separate class for Exception i.e. ExceptionLogger.cs where I have defined the path for exception and used that in all of my classes But the logs are getting inserted into the same normal logs. This problem is occuring with dotnet core 6

Comment: Do you mean the code you have for `restrictedToMinimumLevel` here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serilog different levels for different sinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65899872/serilog-different-levels-for-different-sinks)

Comment: Many other related questions https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=restrictedToMinimumLevel

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want the Exceptions being logged in your normal log? Answers to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56356851/5623232) might help you, either using `Filter` or `Sinks.Map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure serilog like below:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Information)
        .WriteTo.File(
            path: "information.txt"))

    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
        .WriteTo.File(
            path: "error.txt"))
        .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("test Information");
Log.Error("test Error");
```